# Prove that middle point of $PQ$ is a circle

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, circles

Point $A$ is one of the points of intersection of two given intersecting circles. Any line is drawn through $A$ to cut the circles again in $P$ and $Q$. Prove that the locus of middle point of $PQ$ is a circle.

My Attempt:

I was able to obtain the result with difficulty through analytic geometry but is there a geometrical solution to the problem

[image: Solution by Analytic Geometry]

Comment: A lot quicker but still analytic geometry: Let $P_\lambda$ divides $PQ$ internally ($P$ on $S_1$ and $Q$ on $S_2$ as before) with $PP_\lambda:P_\lambda Q=\lambda:1-\lambda$.  The locus of $P_\lambda$ is then given by
$$
\lambda S_1 + (1-\lambda) S_2 = 0
$$
of which yours is the special case $\lambda=\frac12$.

Comment: Please post this as a full solution

Comment: @user10354138 I vaguely recall this, now that you have written. Any link on this topic?

Comment: Oops, it should be $(1-\lambda)S_1+\lambda S_2=0$ instead.

Comment: @user10354138. Can you please elaborate. Is $S_{1}$ a general representation of point $(x_{1},y_{1})$on the circle. Also have you assumed $P_{\lambda}$ to be origin.

Comment: @Maverick No, $S_1$ is defined to be the binary quadratic form $x^2+y^2-2g_1x-2fy$ (as in your image).  $P_\lambda$ is the point $\overrightarrow{OP_\lambda}=(1-\lambda)\overrightarrow{OP}+\lambda\overrightarrow{OQ}$ on the line $PQ$, which is not necessarily the origin.

Comment: @user10354138. But how do you conclude that locus of point $P_{\lambda}$ is a circle.

Comment: @Maverick, coeff of $x^2 =$ coeff of $y^2$ and coeff of $xy=0$ after putting $\lambda = 1/2$.  So its a circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, let me give a quick analytic proof of my claim in the comments.

Choose polar coordinates with $A$ being the origin.  The general equation of circles through $A$ is $r=d\cos(\theta-\theta_0)$ where $d$ is the diameter and $\theta=\theta_0$ is the half-ray containing the diameter through $A$.

So let $r=d_i\cos(\theta-\theta_i)$, $i=1,2$ be the two circles.  For any $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$, the locus of $P_\lambda$ is therefore $$r=(1-\lambda) d_1\cos(\theta-\theta_1)+\lambda d_2\cos(\theta-\theta_2)$$
which yields the Cartesian version $(1-\lambda)S_1+\lambda S_2=0$.